# Dynamically instanciating class using reflection in java fails

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

I have this piece of code

```
List<Class<? extends SubApplication>> appClasses = new ArrayList<Class<? extends SubApplication>>();
List<SubApplication> subApps = new ArrayList<SubApplication>();

// instructions filling "appClasses"
// ... other instructions

for (Class<? extends SubApplication> crtClass : appClasses) {
    try {
        Constructor<? extends SubApplication> constructor = crtClass.getConstructor(new Class<?>[] { Application.class });
        SubApplication subApp = constructor.newInstance(this);
        if (!subApps.contains(subApp)) {
            subApps.add(subApp);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    }
}
```

whereas `this` is an instance of `Application`.

I have several implementations of `SubApplication`. It's part of the contract that all subclasses of this class need to implement a constructor taking a `Application` as parameter.

Now I always receive an `InstanciationException` even though I exactly known that the subclass contains such a constructor. Further details on the exception aren't available: `getMessage()` returns `null`

---

***Edit:*** `SubApplication` is abstract. But `appClasses` only contains **sub**-classes of `SubApplication`

---

***Edit2:*** I had to "construct" the stacktrace, because by contract, I have to catch the exception.

```
sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
ch.migros.gmaare.tk.auth.gui.AuthenticableApp.instanciateSubApps(AuthenticableApp.java:64)
ch.migros.gmaare.tk.auth.gui.AuthenticableApp.<init>(AuthenticableApp.java:42)
ch.migros.gmaare.tk.voicesuite.VoicesuiteApplication.<init>(VoicesuiteApplication.java:34)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.getNewApplication(ApplicationServlet.java:82)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.createApplication(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:978)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.findApplicationInstance(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:801)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:456)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

---

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: SubApplication is not `abstract`?

Comment: yes, it is. And it has both abstract and implemented methods. It also has the constructor taking an `Application`. why?

Comment: post the whole exception stack trace

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract class per definition of the abstract keyword. And the doc is pretty clear about that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Please add code to manage your exceptions. Many people copies code from here. And as jtahlborn said, post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: I'm *not* instanciating the abstract class. I'm trying to instanciate a really existing *subclass* of it.

Comment: @mschonaker: I left them out intentionnally to be as short as possible... And I won't blow up the post with information which is not about the problem.

Comment: @Atmocreations: then please at least replace the entire (broken) exception handling with `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`. Actually you should probably do that in your actual code as well, at least for debugging.

Comment: In the javadocs the only reason for this is attempting to instantiate an abstract class. However, can you post the code of the class being instantiated? you could find out its name by printing it `System.out.println(crtClass.getName())`.

Comment: Ew.  (This is why reflectively creating class objects is best avoided.)

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: is there another way how to enable plugable components?

Comment: Pass a factory object of some kind.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: it is not so strong - if you create new perfect plugable component you have to modify (compile) the factory object or I missed something?

Comment: Yes, that's part of the point.  If the OP had to write a new factory object, s/he would have seen the compile error right there instead of having to track it down and deal with confusing reflection behavior.

Comment: Baah... Dumb enough from me not to verify the classes names. Actually, I've really added `SubApplication` to the list. No wonder it crashes. Therefore: Vote for close. Thanks for your inputs anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comments. I was dumb enough from not to verify the classes names in my array. Actually, I've really added SubApplication to the list. Thanks for your inputs anyway!

Answer (score 2):

When you try this code:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Main {

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        final Class<? extends A>[] classes = new Class[] { B.class, C.class };
        for ( final Class<? extends A> clazz : classes ) {
            try {
                final Constructor<? extends A> constructor = clazz.getConstructor( null );
                final A a = constructor.newInstance( null );
            } catch ( final Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static abstract class A {

    }

    public static class B extends A {

    }

    public static abstract class C extends A {

    }
}
```

You will get same error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

You can modify your code as:

```java
if ( Modifier.isAbstract( clazz.getModifiers() ) ) {
    System.out.println( "skipping" );
} else {
    final A a = constructor.newInstance( null );
}
```